# ls shows a directory but it is inaccessible

Tags: files, symlink, cp, file-copy

I was trying to copy one folder from one location to another. The folder is about 6.4 Gb.

So I did

```
cp -r source_folder level1/val
```

after that, I went into the level1 folder and checked:

```
level1$ ls
val
```

But If I try to cd into val, an error is raised:

```
level1$ cd val
-bash: cd: val: No such file or directory
```

And it does not appear to be copying anything, either:

```
level1$ du -sh val
0   val
```

I also checked with python if the directory exists or not, but it also says that it does not exist

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.exists('level1/val')
False
```

I can't even delete the folder that has been created:

```
level1$ rmdir val
rmdir: failed to remove 'val': Not a directory
```

On the other hand, I was able to delete it as if it was a file:

```
level1$ rm val
level1$ ls
level1$
```

What is going on? And how can I make sure to copy the folder correctly?

**EDIT**
Added the output of `ls -ld source_folder level1/val` which returns

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user1 dinfk      4 Jun 20 12:05 source_folder -> test
drwxr-sr-x 2 user2  systems 4096 Aug 27 19:02 level1/val
```

Comment: What is the output of `ls -ld ource_folder level1/val`?

Comment: @HaukeLaging Added :)

Comment: That is very strange. You should run `fsck` on that volume.

Comment: The number 2 in the second column of `level1/val` listing indicates that there is a hard link to that file-dir thing. My understanding is you can't create hard links to dirs in Bash even though they're technically allowed by the OS. But is it a file or a directory? Except for the `d` indicator it seems like a file.  ... The voodoo going on with that sucker is beyond my pay grade.

Comment: df -h shows different sizes before and after copying? 6,4Gb is sufficiently large to detect this difference.

Comment: What user was attempting the `cp`?  I would expect that `user1` would fail since only the owner, `user2`, has write permission to `level1/val`.

Comment: @EgorVasilyev Do you mean the size of source_folder after performing the command? It is still 6.4 Gb

Comment: @EricTowers It was user2, the owner of level1/val

Comment: Does `user2` have read permission on `/test` and all of its contents?  (The `lrwxrwxrwx` permissions on the link tell us nothing about the permissions at the target of the link.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evidently, the `val` that resulted from the copy the first time round is a broken [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link).

- `ls` lists `val` because it exists: there is a directory entry called `val`.
- `cd val` complains “No such file or directory” because `val` is a broken symbolic link. `cd` needs to access the target of the link, but the target doesn't exist (that's the definition of a broken symlink).
- `du val` shows 0 because a symbolic link doesn't use any storage space. (The space for the name and metadata is not counted.)
- `os.path.exists` returns `False` for broken symbolic links.
- `rmdir val` rightfully complains that `val` is not a directory, since it's a symbolic link.
- `rm val` deletes `val` normally, since `val` is a file that isn't a directory.

You report:

> ```
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 user1 dinfk      4 Jun 20 12:05 source_folder -> test
> ```

The command `cp -r` copies the symbolic link as a symbolic link. Since `source_folder` is a symbolic link whose target is `test`, this results in `level1/val` being a symbolic link whose target is `test`. The target of a symbolic link is a simple string, it doesn't “track” anything. Symbolic links that don't start with a `/` are relative. `level1/val` is a symbolic link whose target is `test` so it points to `level1/test`. Since `level1/test` doesn't exist, the symbolic link is broken.

Later you saw:

> ```
> drwxr-sr-x 2 user2  systems 4096 Aug 27 19:02 level1/val
> ```

This time you did something different and copied a directory tree.

To copy the target of the link rather than the link itself, you can use

```
cp -r source_folder/ level1/val
```

The trailing slash tells the `cp` command to act on the directory that the link points to rather than on the symbolic link itself. If the argument is a directory, this doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Thank you very much! Very clear and informative answer. I used your command and it worked perfectly. Much appreciated! :D

Answer (score 3):

`source_folder` - is symlink that refer to the `test` directory

But you  directory path in symlink is relative. If you use absolute path (e.g. `/home/user/test`) in symlink copying will happen normally.

If you want to copy all files from the directory to which the symbolic link points, you could use `-d` option with `cp` command.

Comment: Thank you! I uses an absolute path to source_folder, but I need to use an absolute path to the folder it links to instead (i.e. test?) Or using -d, so the command would be cp -rd source_folder level1/val ?

Comment: When you create symlink you type path to the folder to which symlink will refer. Example 1: ln -s test source_folder. Example 2: ln -s /home/user/test source_folder. In first example you use relative path and in second example you use absolute path (which start from root directory - /).

Comment: path to source_folder is not the same thing that path in symlink

Answer (score 0):

In case someone also appears to have this particular problem where the proposed solution does not work: Make sure that you really spelled the directory name correctly and pay special attention to special (non-ASCII) characters in its name.

In my case I had the following situation:

```
$ ll
total 68
-rw-r--r-- 1 st_ac131646 st_us-031110 1387 29. Jun 10:02 cu2_o2_nh3_6-1_60.xyz
-rw-r--r-- 1 st_ac131646 st_us-031110 1387 29. Jun 10:03 cu2_o2_nh3_6-2_20.xyz
drwxr-xr-x 2 st_ac131646 st_us-031110 4096 29. Jun 09:17 rḱs
drwxr-xr-x 2 st_ac131646 st_us-031110 4096 29. Jun 13:20 tests
```

But when I tried e.g. `cd rks` or `rmdir rks`, the system would always tell me that no such file or directory existed. I could even do a `mkdir rks` and now all of a sudden there appeared a second directory with this name in the `ls` output (which was accessible as one would expect).

In any case, when you look closer, I must have accidentally created the first directory with a `ḱ` instead of a regular `k` which is why when typing the name as `rks` (instead of  `rḱs`) the system obviously told me that this does not exist.

So long story short: Double-check your spelling and potentially try copy-pasting the name from the `ls` output.